# Google like query for Oracle database

Tags: oracle, search-engine

I want to do a lookup on a column in an Oracle table that contains a company name.

If I ask for "Jennifer's Dry Cleaners" I'd like to return not only that exact match but also "close matches" like (but not limited to):

Jennifer's Pipe Cleaners
Jessica's Dry Cleaners
Jennifer Pipe Cleanup
Pipe Cleaning by Jennifer

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: You'd have better luck making an application that does the querying for you, something to find both the exact match and similar matches. Other than that, tried google? A little research goes a long way. :)

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to us the LIKE operator on each word and combine that with UTL_MATCH.EDIT_DISTANCE to order the results by closeness:

```
SELECT 
    company_name, 
    utl_match.edit_distance(lower(company_name), 'jennifers dry cleaners') edit_distance 
FROM company_names 
WHERE 
     lower(company_name) LIKE '%jennifer%' OR
     lower(company_name) LIKE '%dry%' OR
     lower(company_name) LIKE '%cleaner'
ORDER BY edit_distance asc;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Oracle Text indexes. You can either index a particular column of data, or use a stored procedure to associate a group of terms with a particular record.
Here's an example of indexing a particular column of a table. See documentation on CTX_DDL for how to index using a "Data Store", for indexing multiple columns, even from different sources.

```
9:28:34 AM > create table NOTE_TABLE (NOTE_ID NUMBER constraint 
    NOTE_TABLE_PK primary key, NOTE_TEXT VARCHAR2(4000));

Table created


Executed in 0.045 seconds


9:28:34 AM > insert into NOTE_TABLE values(1, 'This is the contents 
    of a note that has the word "glory"');

1 row inserted


Executed in 0.023 seconds


9:28:34 AM > insert into NOTE_TABLE values(2, 'Mine eyes have see the 
    Glory of the coming of the LORD');

1 row inserted


Executed in 0.01 seconds



9:51:15 AM> insert into NOTE_TABLE values(3, 'This is Jennifer''s Pipe cleaning');

1 row inserted


Executed in 0.008 seconds


9:28:34 AM > commit;

Commit complete


Executed in 0.014 seconds


9:28:34 AM > begin
                             2   ctx_ddl.create_preference('my_word_list', 'BASIC_WORDLIST');
                             3   ctx_ddl.set_attribute('my_word_list','FUZZY_MATCH','ENGLISH');
                             4   ctx_ddl.set_attribute('my_word_list','FUZZY_SCORE','65');
                             5   ctx_ddl.set_attribute('my_word_list','FUZZY_NUMRESULTS','5000');
                             6   ctx_ddl.set_attribute('my_word_list','SUBSTRING_INDEX','TRUE');
                             7   ctx_ddl.set_attribute('my_word_list','PREFIX_INDEX','YES');
                             8   ctx_ddl.set_attribute('my_word_list','PREFIX_MIN_LENGTH', 1);
                             9   ctx_ddl.set_attribute('my_word_list','PREFIX_MAX_LENGTH', 64);
                            10   ctx_ddl.set_attribute('my_word_list','STEMMER','ENGLISH');
                            11   end;
                            12  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed


Executed in 0.024 seconds


9:28:34 AM > CREATE INDEX NOTE_TABLE_TEXT_IX on NOTE_TABLE(NOTE_TEXT) indextype is
                             2  ctxsys.CONTEXT parameters ('wordlist my_word_list');

Index created


Executed in 0.321 seconds


9:28:35 AM > select NOTE_ID from NOTE_TABLE t where contains(NOTE_TEXT, '{glory}', 10) > 0;

   NOTE_ID
----------
         1
         2

Executed in 0.101 seconds


9:28:35 AM > select NOTE_ID from NOTE_TABLE t where contains(NOTE_TEXT, '{glory} and {lord}', 10) > 0;

   NOTE_ID
----------
         2

Executed in 0.055 seconds

9:51:16 AM> select NOTE_ID from NOTE_TABLE t where contains(NOTE_TEXT, 'fuzzy(cleaners, 1, 3)', 10) > 0;

   NOTE_ID
----------
         3

Executed in 0.056 seconds


9:28:35 AM > drop table NOTE_TABLE;

Table dropped


Executed in 0.283 seconds


9:28:35 AM > begin
                             2    ctx_ddl.drop_preference('my_word_list');
                             3  end;
                             4  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed


Executed in 0.012 seconds


9:28:36 AM >
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).